# How to align the ko validation message when it is long

Tags: jquery, html, css, validation, knockout.js

I have used ko validation messages to validate input field. How to align the validation message on wrap to the specified place

```
<input id="personName" class="form-control placeholder has-error" type="text"
 data-bind="value: name" style="width:225px;">
ko.validation.init({insertMessages: true});
var vm = {
    name: ko.observable('name').extend({required: { message: "Please enter a username.", params: true }, email: { message: "Username should be in a valid email address format which is used.", params: true }})
}
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

my codes are in http://jsfiddle.net/Td7zZ/2/

[image]

Comment: you have to bind it in a element text has a free flow behavior

Comment: Ur fiddle doesn't work ??

Comment: How about showing error msg below the Textbox?

Comment: @Anup fiddle is working for me

Comment: @Anup take out the name, -Pandiyan, is fixed width acceptable? also can we change the DOM

Comment: @Anup i was supposed to do in it right side only

Comment: Didn't get u, Mr.Alien??

Comment: @Resource-guru.com i can't get you

Comment: @PandiyanCool can we alter the DOM?

Comment: @Mr.Alien if possible do it in css otherwise edit DOM at lastt

Comment: KnockOut.js was indeed blocked on my place...thats y not working on myside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to alter your DOM for that, so that we will have a fixed `width` container, and than we will `float` `input` as well as the JS generated `span` to the `left`, and will assign them a fixed `width` or you can `float` them to the `left` and `right` as well

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Td7zZ/4/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/Td7zZ/5/) *(Floating `left` and `right`)*

[**Demo 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/Td7zZ/6/) *Multiple `input` elements nested under `ul` and `li` with self clearing `li`*

```
div {
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.form-control, .form-control + span {
    float: left;
}

.form-control {
    width: 200px;
}

.form-control + span {
    width: 270px;
}
```

Note: If you have more than one `input` field, than use `ul` and `li` elements, and make sure you `clear` the `float` after each `li`

Answer (score 1):

Add css to your input like :

```
input, .form-control {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    width: 225px;
}
```

Comment: if this can fix his issue then whats the problem?

Comment: @Era he is saying that it will work for fiddle but if you have more than input field?

Comment: Am not saying you are wrong, am saying that it will just fail when you have more elements in the `form` and as you are using `float` without any wrapper element, it will sit one besides another so I asked him whether we can modify the DOM or not :)  --> http://jsfiddle.net/Td7zZ/7/

Comment: ohhk .. my bad.. then you need to add a wrapper or put a clear div after every input tag.

Answer (score 0):

It's need to bind the css into div that will apply into all tags. Something like this

```
<div data-bind="attr: { class: 'wrap'}" > 

  <input id="personName" class="form-control placeholder has-error" type="text" 
    data-bind="  value: name " style="width:225px;"  />

</div>
```

Here is the css..

```
  .wrap {
    width:500px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid blue;
  }
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Td7zZ/9/)